# .NET TreeViewItem Selected only when itself is selected, not its child?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeviewitem

Currently, I have a tree view that looks like this:

```
+Country
  +StateA
    -CityA
    -CityB
  +StateB
    -CityC
  +State
    -CityD
```

Where the Cities are the end leaves of the tree and are selectable and have their own `Selected` handler. The Country is also selectable and has its own `Selected` handler.

The handlers are assigned as so:

```
countryTreeItem.Selected += countrySelectedHandler;
...
cityTreeItem.Selected += citySelectedHandler;
```

When I select a City, the parent State and the parent Country are also selected. This means that both `citySelectedHandler` and `countrySelectedHandler` are selected when I select a leaf (Say, `City A`)

Is there a way to make sure that only the leaf item gets selected? If I click on `CityA` I only want `citySelectedHandler` for that City to run, instead of `countrySelectedHandler` of its ancestor to run also.

However, I still want `countrySelectedHandler` to run when the Country is selected (clicked on). Simply removing the handler for the ancestor won't do.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop propagation of the event, you can set `e.Handled = true`. This way the event will not bubble up to the ancestor tree items.